# Appending something to the result of scan.next() in Java

Tags: java

I have

```
String add_data[] = new String[6];
```

then I do

```
System.out.println("COMPANY NAME: ");
add_data[0] = scan.next();
```

I need to append a character to what to get from scan.next() & put that into add_data[0]. Please guide me how to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `scan` refers to [java.util.Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) this can be accomplished easily:

```
add_data[0] = scan.next() + 'c';
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's use a well-named function.

```
public String nextLine(Scanner aInputStream) {
    return (aInputStream.next() + 'x');
}

add_data[0] = nextLine(new Scanner());
```

Well free to tuck that Scanner parameter into the function as a local variable if it bothers you.